# Angularjs 2 getting an error when adding 'routing' to imports in app.module.ts

Tags: angular, routes

I am getting an error whenever I add 'routing' to the imports in `app.module.ts`

```
app/app.routing.ts(18,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ModuleWithProvider'.
[0] app/app.routing.ts(18,65): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AppRoutes'.
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

import { SearchComponent }  from './components/search/search.component';
import { NavbarComponent }  from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { AboutComponent }  from './components/about/about.component';

import { routing }  from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, routing ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,
                  SearchComponent,
                  NavbarComponent,
                  AboutComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**routing file**

```
import {ModuleWithProviders} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import {SearchComponent} from './components/search/search.component';
import {AboutComponent} from './components/about/about.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    component:SearchComponent
  },
  {
    path:'about',
    component:AboutComponent
  }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProvider = RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes);
```

Comment: Please provide more code. How do your routes and `@NgModule()` look like

Comment: You probably need to `import { ModuleWithProviders } from @angular/core'` in your routes file. And what is `AppRoutes` (should it be `Routes`)? Please show your routing file

Comment: I just added the route file and ngModule.

Comment: `AppRoutes` should be lowercase

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is solution.

You have two typos in your code.

**routing file**

```
import {ModuleWithProviders} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import {SearchComponent} from './components/search/search.component';
import {AboutComponent} from './components/about/about.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    component:SearchComponent
  },
  {
    path:'about',
    component:AboutComponent
  }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

At the last line you wrote ModuleWithProvider instead ModuleWithProvider**s** and also AppRoutes instead **a**ppRoutes